# How to use attr in elements within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attr

So, I have an array with 200 items called "icone", and when I use this code:

```
icone.attr('src', 'img/known.svg');
```

All items change according to what is in the code.
But how do I do if I want to change only 1 of the items in this array, and not all 200?

I tried with:

```
icone[0].attr('src', 'img/known.svg');
```

But the console returned "icone[0].attr is not a function".

Any ideas on how to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: It would be `icone[0].src = 'img/known.svg'`. jQuery's functions generally only work on jQuery collections, not generic arrays of elements. If `icone` is a jQuery collection, then it'd be `icone.eq(0).attr(src, 'img/known.svg')`.

Comment: let icone001 = $("img:first-child");
icone001.attr("src","img/known.svg");
console.log(icone001]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is absolutely necessary to use jQuery in this case. You can do this:

```
$(icone[0]).attr('src', 'img/known.svg');
```

In case it is not, you can do it as the other answers say.

Comment: *"you must do"* .... well actually there are numerous other ways like `first()` or `eq(0)` on original collection

Answer (score 0):

Once you do `icone[0]`, you're dealing with a raw node, not a jQuery "wrapper." That raw element does not have an `.attr` function.

As Ouroborus suggests, just set the attribute directly by doing `icone[0].src = ...`.

(If Ouroborus submits an answer in addition to their comment, you should mark it as accepted, not this answer. I just wanted to explain why what you're doing doesn't work.)

EDIT: Interestingly, `icone.first().attr(...)` *does* work, because it does wrap the first element with a jQuery wrapper.